# Ajax transfer type gets overwriten by url

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have an ajax call that has a generated url via a paginator script:

```
"http://192.168.1.23:8000/pricing/0/999/null/?page=9"
```

Quite the same link is generated on the server:

```
"https://xxx.xxx.xxx/pricing/0/999/null/?page=9
```

The links are passed to this ajax call, in this case set as `data`:

```
$.ajax({
            url: (data) ? data : '/pricing/' + this.state.country + '/' + this.state.operation + '/' + this.state.optional,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                _token: window.token
            },
            success: function (e) {
                $('#loader-wrapper').fadeOut();
                this.setState({
                    paginator: true,
                    menuActive: false
                });
                this.handleArticles(e);
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (err) { alert(err);
                console.log(err);

            }

        })
```

On localhost the next page is loaded without any problems, but on the server I get an error `405 - Method Not Allowed`.

I'm using a combination of react.js and laravel. My route for this kind of link is:

```
post('pricing/{country}/{operation}/{page}', 'PricingController@getArticles');
```

I only know method not allowed errors from a `get request` to a `post` route, but that's not the case as ajax is performing a post call though there is some "get data" attached, and more important, it's working on localhost. Does somebody have an explanation for this and how could I solve it?

**EDIT**

I solved it by adding a `get()` route. So here's my new question:

How can an ajax type being overwriten by simply passing a url containing get data?

Comment: I sorry i would like to ask about the code,
success:function(){}.bind(this), you don't receive any errors?

Comment: post an answer and check it!

Answer (score 0):

Is the url that you want to target is located in another site ? If yes, then it might be CORS so your url call needs to return the following headers

Access-Control-Allow-Origin  : *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Origin, SecurityPrivateKeyID
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS

Comment: Are you able to post the response & request site vs localhost?