# jQuery Ajax POST request being sent as GET with Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, laravel

I'm having a little trouble with Ajax. My project is in `Laravel 5` and it's running on `Apache` and `rewrite` is enabled and the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware is in place. I'm trying to send a POST request to another route inside my project. Here's what my Ajax looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/add-device/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    },
        error: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

When I click the button that triggers this Ajax, I get a `405: MethodNotAllowed` response. So I went into `routes.php` and I added a GET route. I've also included my POST route:

```
Route::get('add-device', function()
{
    return 'hello';
});

Route::post('add-device', [
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'FormController@add_device'
]);
```

I get the 'hello' message, so this is being sent as GET instead of POST. I tried to use `$.post` instead of `$.ajax` to force the POST but I still get the same behavior. For good measure, here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also tried the Ajax without the trailing slash because of the rewrite rule (`/add-device`) but I get the same 'hello' message.

I tested all of my Ajax requests (half GET, half POST) during development and they worked fine while being served with `artisan`. I've only had this problem come up after switching to `Apache`. I've moved into the QA phase of my project and so I moved the project onto our development server, which is running `Apache 2.4.10` on `Debian 8`.

Anyone have any ideas on what is going on and how to resolve it?

---

#### Additional Content

```
Exception trace:
 () at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:901
 Illuminate\Foundation\Application->abort() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:21
 abort() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/app/Handlers/Events/AbortTheRequest.php:28
 App\Handlers\Events\AbortTheRequest->handle() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php:327
 Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure}() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php:218
 Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->fire() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:650
 event() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/app/Services/ZipHelper.php:56
 App\Services\ZipHelper->__construct() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/app/Services/DashHelper.php:43
 App\Services\DashHelper->__construct() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/app/Http/Controllers/DashController.php:28
 App\Http\Controllers\DashController->__construct() at n/a:n/a
 ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:817
 Illuminate\Container\Container->build() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:656
 Illuminate\Container\Container->make() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:644
 Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:161
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getControllerMiddleware() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:142
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getMiddleware() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:109
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getRouteInformation() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:89
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getRoutes() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:75
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->fire() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:523
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:115
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:101
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /home/debian/public_html/ZipPrinter/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
```

Comment: Are your routes cached? Try running `php artisan route:clear` to make sure you're not dealing with some old cache. Also, make sure the route is really being registered with `php artisan route:list`. Also, the obligatory `php artisan clear-compiled`, `composer dump-auto` and `php artisan optimize` might help.

Comment: I went ahead and cleared the cache but when I ran the route list I get a `NotFoundHttpException`.

Comment: Wait - you get a NotFoundHttpException whe you run `php artisan route:list` in your console?

Comment: Yes, but in the browser my routes are working because my links are working. I'm in the middle of getting composer right now to finish the dump-autoload.

Comment: If `php artisan route:list` throws an Exception then there's clearly something wrong in your application. Could you please post the whole stacktrace? Also, you should remove the trailing slash from your URL, the redirect might be causing the problem.

Comment: I finished up and tried again and I have the same results.

Comment: I had exactly the same behaviour with an ajax post request yesterday. Are you sure that there a no trailing question marks? Also, did you try this ajax url: /add-device? My question from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065712/ajax-transfer-type-gets-overwriten-by-url

Comment: No, I don't have any trailing ?. I did try to remove the trailing / but that didn't change the behavior.

Comment: Could you please also add the excact Exception message (i.e. *all* the output that comes after you run the route:list command). What type of request do you see in the network section of e. g. Chrom Developer Tools? And what happens if you remove the auth middleware?

Comment: The only other line is `[Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException]` and I ran artisan with `-v`. Developer tools tell me the request is GET.

Comment: This is really weird... Do you have any logic in your routes file, maybe test routes with closures or something, or is just simple url-controller-mapping? And are you absolutely sure that you the right JavaScript is loaded on the client side? If you're working with elixir, make sure everything is compiled correctly on the staging server or uses the compiled files from dev. Which version of Jquery are you using? (sorry for so many questions, don't know what's relevant and what's not, just trying to get an idea of what's going on, because this is a really strange and interesting problem... :))

Comment: Can you check your browser console to make sure it's actually submitting the request as a post?

Comment: I am using jQuery `1.11.1`. My routes file is a simple controller mapping. I do have one closure, and that is the one I posted above in the code for the get route. I am not working with any compiled js or css. I am refreshing the browser for any local javascript changes. I am also checking the source when I do that to make sure the browser isn't caching the javascript. I'll go ahead a clear my cache and try again just to make sure. The console tells me the request is GET when it gives me the 405.

Comment: That would make this a client side issue and nothing to do with your routes or Laravel for that matter.  Instead of `type: 'post'`, try `method: 'post'`.  I have a feeling this is a jquery bug because there are numerous questions here with the same issue.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely a client-side issue. But the problem is that it is being sent as GET instead of POST. It shouldn't be doing that because I told jQuery to use POST. I changed it to type after a suggestion from another SO thread. It didn't work with method either.

Comment: Sorry just wanted to make it clear for everyone else because there is a lot of focus on exceptions, routes, .htaccess, etc.

Comment: Understandable. I simply added that stuff because I only changed the environment and so I wanted to be as specific as possible about the environment in case it did have something to do with, say, a rewrite rule.

Comment: Try grabbing a fresh copy of jquery.  I tried to recreate this with `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js` and the only way I could was when I had both `method` and `type` options set in which case `method` always overwrites `type`.

Comment: as of api.jquery.com version >=1.9 method is added, use method instead of type and check. one more thing is that can you use $.post() instead? And make sure all the code is working perfectly. no error is thrown in your js.

Comment: Yes, I've tried $.post() and I get the same results (405). I also updated jQuery to 1.11.3 and changed type to method to no avail.

Comment: did you check browser console ? is it showing any error ? I found that if you have any error from your js, Ajax doesn't work as expected.

Comment: The only error that I get is the 405. And the rest of my javascript works just fine.

Comment: I was actually able to reproduce the behaviour: The trailing slash in `url: '/add-device/'` seems to be crucial. When I omit it, it ignores the ajax settings and makes a GET request, if I leave it there, it correctly makes a POST request. I'm not quite sure yet why this is, seems to be some HTTP sepcific stuff. With Jquery 2.1, however, the POST works with both, but I get a 301 response for the url with a trailing slash - which is actually expected behaviour defined in the .htaccess. But it still does make a POST request first. So maybe, if possible, you should upgrade your Jquery version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I removed the trailing slash and it suddenly worked. I'm not sure why exactly it did, but it did. I posted this question to [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/ajax-issues-on-apache-server) as well. I would recommend that those having the same issue I did to read through the comments and through this other thread so they can follow my steps. I think one of my previous steps resolved a problem so that when I removed the trailing slash this time, it worked. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

removed the trailing slash from ajax request url worked for me

Answer (score -1):

try this for your post route

```
Route::post('add-device', [
    'as' => 'add_device.post'
    'middleware' => 'auth',
    'uses' => 'FormController@add_device'
]);
```

Comment: I tried that but I still get a 405 MethodNotAllowed.

Comment: Can you post your routes files and a screenshot of the console with the failed request?